# Real trouble importing CSV with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I've exported as a CSV file.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting it imported.  It looks something along the lines of this:

`Web_Site_Member_ID,Master_Member_ID,API_GUID,Constituent_ID,Registration_Date,Approved_Site_Member,Date_Approved,Date_Last_Login,Member_Suspended,Last_Updated,Date_Membership_Expires,Membership,Has_Donated_Online,Date_Last_Donated,Has_Purchased_Online,Date_Last_Purchased,Has_Registered_Event_Online,Date_Last_Event_Reg,Username,Password,Member_Type_Code,Primary_Group_Code,Gender,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,Nickname,Member_Name_Suffix,Member_Name_Title,Birthdate,Marriage_Status,Maiden_Name,Anniversary_Date,Spouse_Name,Email_Address,Email_Address_Alternate,Email_Bounced,Messenger_Type,Messenger_Handle,Home_Address_Line1,Home_Address_Line2,Home_City,Home_Location,Home_State_Abbrev,Home_Postal_Code,Home_Country,Personal_Website,Home_Phone_Area_Code,Home_Phone,Mobile_Area_Code,Mobile,Employer_Name,Professional_Title,Profession,Employer_Address_Line1,Employer_Address_Line2,Employer_City,Employer_Location,Employer_State_Abbrev,Employer_Postal_Code,Employer_Country,Employer_Website,Employer_Phone_Area_Code,Employer_Phone,Employer_Fax_Area_Code,Employer_Fax,Resume_Exists,Resume_Headline,Social_Organizations,Education_and_Experience,More_Personal_Info,Search_Identifier,Internal_Comments,Home_Address_Validated,Employer_Address_Validated,Date_Last_Renewed,Date_Effective_Membership_Expires,Import_Batch_ID,Career_Openings_Allowed,Members_Pages_Allowed,Additional_Seats_Allowed`

And I'm trying to import it using PHPMyAdmin to MySQL.

On each new line is an entry, its all person data but it follows the format you would expect:

123456678,,1-2-3-4-5-6,123345456,01/01/1901 00:00,Yes,01/01/2001 13:09,,No,01/01/2001 13:09,,,No,,No,,No,,1@1.come,111222333444555,Emeritus_TAD,,,... etc etc

Every time I try and import it I get errors. If I say

```
#1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type,
not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

#### At first I thought it wasn't recognising the end of the first line of text.

So next up I made sure that it knew that the first line was just the titles by checking the

```
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL'
```

Which is weird, as I can't see any null columns in the first row.

#### Previously I had been removing the `"` from the "Columns enclosed with:" input, as I could only see them on certain ones, so I tried putting this back in.

This time I got the following:

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

What is wrong with my CSV file / PHPMyAdmin?! I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of `max_allowed_packet`

Change in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now restart the MySQL service once you are done. You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html